# Multilevel Dropdown Menu Issues with Jquery

Tags: jquery, menu

So, first let me say I am not highly skilled in coding...

Here is my issue:

My dropdown works, but it displays the third level submenu when the first level is hovered over.  It is displaying the whole stack instead of each individual level as a user chooses to move down.  I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I can't seem to get it.  I should say too, that the list is being pulled from a wordpress menu...

see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MkR7W/)

and the live site [here](http://epic4life.com/)

Comment: I guess users who navigate with the keyboard are just out of luck eh?

Answer (score 1):

You should change selector to get first level children as

```
J('>ul', this).slideDown(100);
```