# jquery multilevel left menu

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#content').hide();
    jQuery('#last').mouseover(function () {});
    jQuery('#content').on('mouseout', function () {});
});
```

this is my code in this i have two divs...
i need output multi level left menu....... check this link http://javascript-array.com/scripts/multi_level_drop_down_menu/?j like this i need to display i am not much aware of jquery can you please help in this regard

This is my jsp code

```
<div class="nav-menu nav-menu-style-<%= bulletStyle %>" >


        <c:choose>
            <c:when test='<%= (headerType.equals("root-layout") && (rootLayout != null)) %>'>

                <%
                String layoutURL = PortalUtil.getLayoutURL(rootLayout, themeDisplay);
                String target = PortalUtil.getLayoutTarget(rootLayout);
                String layoutName = rootLayout.getName(themeDisplay.getLocale());
                %>

                <h2>
                    <a href="<%= layoutURL %>" <%= target %>><%= layoutName %></a>
                </h2>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test='<%= headerType.equals("portlet-title") %>'>
                <h2><%= themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getTitle() %></h2>
            </c:when>
            <c:when test='<%= headerType.equals("breadcrumb") %>'>
                   <p id="last"> <liferay-ui:breadcrumb /></p>
            </c:when>
        </c:choose>
<div id="content">
        <%
        if (!hidden) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            _buildNavigation(rootLayout, layout, selBranch, themeDisplay, 1, includedLayouts, nestedChildren, sb);

            String content = sb.toString();

            /*if (!nestedChildren) {
                content = StringUtil.replace(content, "</a><ul class", "</a></li></ul><ul class");
                content = StringUtil.replace(content, "</ul></li>", "</ul><ul class=\"layouts\">");
            }*/
        %>

            <%= content %>

        <%
        }
        %>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: where is your html code?

Answer (score 0):

1.[Multilevel Dropdown Menu Issues with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706488/multilevel-dropdown-menu-issues-with-jquery)

2.http://jsfiddle.net/MkR7W/3/

Hope it will give u an idea to solve this pblm.